# Eventhough i handled FormatException this code outputs unhandled FormatException when i give letters instead of numbers?

Tags: c#, exception

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace pgm 
{
    class CalculatorExceptions
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1,num2;
            string operand;
            Console.WriteLine("+ Add\n- Subtract\n* Multiply\n/ Division\nSelect your operation");
            operand = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter any two values");
            num1=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            num2=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            var opr = new operations();
            try
            {
            switch(operand)
            {
                case "+":
                    opr.Addition(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    opr.Subtraction(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case "*":
                    opr.Multiplication(num1,num2);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    opr.Division(num1,num2);
                    break;
            }
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input string was not in a correct format\nResult: 0");
            }
           }
    }
    class operations{
        public void Addition(int num1,int num2)
        {
            int res;
            res = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",res);
        }
        public void Subtraction(int num1,int num2)
        {
            int res;
            res = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",res);
        }
        public void Multiplication(int num1,int num2)
        {
            int res;
            res = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",res);
        }
        public void Division(int num1,int num2)
        {
            int res;
            res = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}",res);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your try-catch doesn't surround the block that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Use int.TryParse instead

Answer (score 2):

The sources of the exception are parsing: if any `Console.ReadLine()` is of *incorrect format* (say, `"bla-bla-bla"`) `FormatException` will be thrown

```
// Potential source of FormatException 
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
// Potential source of FormatException 
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

*Simple patch*: put `Convert` (I've changed it into `Parse` for readability) within the `try`:

```
 try {
    // Potential source of FormatException 
    num1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    // Potential source of FormatException 
    num2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var opr = new operations();
    ...
 } 
 catch(FormatException) {
   Console.WriteLine("Input string was not in a correct format\nResult: 0");
 }
```

*Better solution*: `int.TryParse` (and no `try .. catch` at all):

```
 // If we fail to parse any user input
 if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num1) || 
     !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num2)) {
   // show message and return
   Console.WriteLine("Input string was not in a correct format\nResult: 0");

   return; 
 }
```

Comment: You are correct about the problem, of course, but IMHO, quite wrong about the remedy. Why wrap `parse` inside a `try...catch` block when you can simply use `TryParse`? As Eric Lippert have written a decade ago, that's a classic example of a [vexing exception](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)...

Comment: @Zohar Peled: you are quite right, thank you! `int.Parse` is not a remedy but a simple patch; `int.TryParse` is the solution

Comment: I was actually quite surprised when I've read the previous version of your answer. I'm used to read very high quality answers from you... well, now that the answer contains TryParse, I can (and did) upvote it :-)

Comment: @Zohar Peled: I'm sorry for my succumbing to temptation to put evident easy to implement *patching* code, which is, however, is not a correct answer *solving* the problem. Several seconds pause to think over a question "If I faced the problem what code I would implement" is an essential thing.